# How to particular key's value in an object based on the values from another array and using arrays sequence in mind

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an object with its key-value pair and based on the value from another array which is having only key which match the objects key. i wanted to form a different array. keeping in mind the sequence of the array and same way i want to make another array with only values of the object.

i have tried with object.entries and using forEach to key through the object but unable to get the desired results.

```
var arrayLegends = ["totalregisteredfirst","totalregisteredsecond", "totalregisteredfourth"];

var lengendsObj = {totalregisteredfirst: "1st visit", totalregisteredfourth: "4th visit", totalregisteredsecond: "2nd visit"}

var legendsValue = [];

Object.entries(lengendsObj).forEach(function([objKey, objValue]) {
  arrayLegends.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value === objKey ) {
      legendsValue.push(objValue);
    }
  });
});

console.log('legends value', legendsValue);
```

Expected Resultant Array = [ '1st visit', '2nd visit', '4th visit' ];

Actual Resultant Array = [ '1st visit', '4th visit', '2nd visit' ];

Answer (score 1):

Since `arrayLegends` is containing the keys you want to retrieve in `legendsObj` in the right order, you only have to iterate through `arrayLegends` and push the corresponding values in `legendsValue`:

```js
var arrayLegends = ["totalregisteredfirst","totalregisteredsecond", "totalregisteredfourth"];

var lengendsObj = {totalregisteredfirst: "1st visit", totalregisteredfourth: "4th visit", totalregisteredsecond: "2nd visit"}

var legendsValue = [];

arrayLegends.forEach(function(value) {
  legendsValue.push(lengendsObj[value]);
});
  
console.log('legends value', legendsValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

```
let arrayLegends = ["totalregisteredfirst","totalregisteredsecond", "totalregisteredfourth"];

let lengendsObj = {totalregisteredfirst: "1st visit", totalregisteredfourth: "4th visit", totalregisteredsecond: "2nd visit"}

var legendsValue = arrayLegends.map((key) => lengendsObj[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really close to getting your desired result, you just need use your `arrayLegends` as the outer loop and your `Object.entries(lengendsObj)` for your inner loop:

```js
var arrayLegends = ["totalregisteredfirst","totalregisteredsecond", "totalregisteredfourth"];

var lengendsObj = {totalregisteredfirst: "1st visit", totalregisteredfourth: "4th visit", totalregisteredsecond: "2nd visit"}

var legendsValue = [];

arrayLegends.forEach(function (value) {
 Object.entries(lengendsObj).forEach(function([objKey, objValue]) {
  if (value === objKey ) {
    legendsValue.push(objValue);
  }
 });
});

console.log('legends value', legendsValue);
```

Comment: Why iterate over the legendsObj when you can directly get the value from object since you already have the key?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal I wanted to show OP how close he was to get his desired result. But for sure, the runtime can be greatly improved from the n^2 operation in mine and OP's posts. Your answer is really good in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

[Object order is not guaranteed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/11059449). Iterating over an object will not necessarily be done in the same order on independent runs. Iterate over your array instead; that *does* have guaranteed order.

```js
var arrayLegends = ["totalregisteredfirst","totalregisteredsecond", "totalregisteredfourth"];

var legendsObj = {totalregisteredfirst: "1st visit", totalregisteredfourth: "4th visit", totalregisteredsecond: "2nd visit"}

var legendsValue = [];

arrayLegends.forEach(k => {
    legendsValue.push(legendsObj[k]);
});
```